# TikZ: matrix in a matrix gives "missing $"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

The following TikZ code compiles and renders as expected:

```
\matrix[struct]
{
    \node[varname] (age) {age}; & \node[vartype] {int*}; \\
    \node[varname] {height}; & \node[vartype] {float}; \\
    \node[varname] {weight}; & \node[vartype] {float}; \\
};
```

[image]

The following does not:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[struct] (person)
{
    \node[varname] {name}; & \node[vartype] {const char*}; \\
    \node[varname] {attributes}; & 

    \matrix[struct] (foo) 
    {
        \node[varname] (age) {age}; & \node[vartype] {int*}; & \\
        \node[varname] {height}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
        \node[varname] {weight}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
    }; \\
    \node[varname] {next}; & TODO & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> `Missing $ inserted.`

Why not? How to I get a matrix-in-a-matrix?

The objective is to represent data types and structures hierarchically. If a data structure `Primary` contains another data structure `Secondary`, then I need to be able to include/invoke the code which draws `Secondary` inside the code which draws `Primary`. I need to be able to uniquely name nodes within any given structure, so that I can attach arbitrary decorations to them. ASCII art:

```
PRIMARY----------------------+
| basic_field:   int         |
| complex_field: SECONDARY--+|
|                | foo: int ||    ______
|                | bar: int<======|note|
|                | baz: int ||    ^^^^^^
|                -----------+|
| basic_field_2: int         |
+----------------------------+
```

Comment: People don't like to get source from external sources that might not be available later on. Place the code here instead. It is short enough

Comment: BTW: several constructions does not like blank lines, so try removing that blank line before the inner matrix. Removing that blank line will give you the answer. BTW2: what even use a matrix for this?

Comment: Edited, thanks for the advice. What would you use instead of a matrix? I tried with just nodes but had to write a lot of `[left=of blah]` and that was a lot of typing, requiring me to name all the nodes.

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want to achieve in the end? Is it just about arranging some words in a grid-fashion, or do you also want to draw lines connecting the entries?

Comment: I'm with gernot, explian better what exactly it is you want, then we'll see that we can come up with

Comment: Edited to add a diagram.

Comment: I get a "you cannot nest pgfmatrix environments" message.  Interestingly, you get the same message with a pic, and you can't put one in a savebox either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation on Segletes' solution:

Note: `(foo)` and `(age)` will not be defined in the final tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}% Really?

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}

\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(age.text)]
\matrix[struct] (foo)
    {
        \node[varname] (age) {age}; & \node[vartype] {int*}; & \\
        \node[varname] {height}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
        \node[varname] {weight}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[struct] (person)
{
    \node[varname] {name}; & \node[vartype] {const char*}; \\
    \node[varname] {attributes}; & \node{\usebox{\tempbox}}; \\
    \node[varname] {next}; & TODO  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: A definite improvement.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, although it doesn't allow me to decorate the nodes properly (see the ASCII art in my original question, and [this followup question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357502/tikz-node-in-picture-in-picture-can-be-referenced-but-is-in-the-wrong-place).)

Comment: The fix is to add the option `remember picture` to both `tikzpicture` environments.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit ugly, because I din't know that `standalone` builds each `tikzpicture` in its own page (hat tip to John K in comment).  Thus, there exists a `standalone` border around the outside of the inner `struct` box.  Because of it, I have to resort to `\\[-10pt]` to eliminate the vertical border around the inner box and `\hspace{-10pt}` to eliminate the horizontal border.  I give an **ADDENDUM** below showing how that whole issue disappears when not using `standalone`.

Even if that is fixed, it is still a bit ugly, as I must build the inner box in a separate `\vbox` and save that, to be regurgitated within the outer box.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}
%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\insertmatrix[1]{%
  \hspace{-10pt}%
  \belowbaseline[-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\ht\strutbox\relax]{#1}%
  \hspace{-10pt}%
}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}

\setbox0=\vbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[struct] (foo) 
    {
        \node[varname] (age) {age}; & \node[vartype] {int*}; & \\
        \node[varname] {height}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
        \node[varname] {weight}; & \node[vartype] {float}; & \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\savestack\mycomplex{\box0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[struct] (person)
{
    \node[varname] {name}; & \node[vartype] {const char*}; \\[-10pt]
    \node[varname] {attributes}; & \insertmatrix{\mycomplex} 
      \\[-10pt]
    \node[varname] {next}; & TODO  \\
    \node[varname] {afternext}; & MORE TODO  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM**

Thanks to John for pointing out the issue being with `standalone`, not `tikz`.  If I perform the task in `article` class, all those `10pt` corrections are not needed, and the `\vbox` can be put into an `\hbox`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}
%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\insertmatrix[1]{%
  \belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{#1}%
}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}

\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix[struct,ampersand replacement=\&] (foo) 
    {
        \node[varname] (age) {age}; \& \node[vartype] {int*}; \& \\
        \node[varname] {height}; \& \node[vartype] {float}; \& \\
        \node[varname] {weight}; \& \node[vartype] {float}; \& \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\savestack\mycomplex{\box0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[struct] (person)
{
    \node[varname] {name}; & \node[vartype] {const char*}; \\
    \node[varname] {attributes}; & \insertmatrix{\mycomplex} 
      \\
    \node[varname] {next}; & TODO  \\
    \node[varname] {afternext}; & MORE TODO  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \setbox0=\hbox{} also works, while \savebox doesn't.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I could not get it to work with `\hbox`.

Comment: The [tikz] option to standalone puts every tikzpicture on a new page.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks.  That explains a lot, and I have edited my answer to reflect that new information.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use plain LaTeX for the grid-like arrangements and tikz for annotations. Instead of `\fbox` you can use fancier methods of drawing nice boxes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\vartype[1]{\textcolor{red}{\ttfamily#1}}
\newcommand\varname[1]{{\ttfamily#1}}
\newcommand\struct[1]%
  {\fbox
    {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll@{}}
     #1
     \end{tabular}%
    }%
  }
\newcommand\tikznode[2]%
  {\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]\node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}

\begin{document}
\struct
  {\varname{name}       & \vartype{const char*} \\
   \varname{attributes}
   & \struct
       {\varname{age}    & \vartype{int*}  \\
        \varname{height} & \tikznode{heighttype}{\vartype{floatp}} \\
        \varname{weight} & \vartype{float}
       } \\[7ex]
   \varname{next}       & TODO
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[stealth-,shorten <=2pt] (heighttype) -- +(1,1) node[right] {important!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```