# TikZ: node-in-picture-in-picture can be referenced but is in the wrong place

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

This is an issue with [an answer to a previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357456/tikz-matrix-in-a-matrix-gives-missing/357491#357491):

The proposed solution uses a picture-within-a-picture. As its author noted:

> Note: `(foo)` and `(age)` will not be defined in the final tikzpicture.

It makes sense to me that an included picture would be in some sense atomic, but I wanted to see how it would break if I tried to reference an inner picture's node from the outer picture:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}% Really?

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}
\tikzset{structtype/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=white,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}

\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(age.text)]
\matrix[struct] (attributes)
    {
        \node[varname] (age) {age};    & \node[vartype]       {int*}; & \\
        \node[varname]       {height}; & \node[vartype]       {float}; & \\
        \node[varname]       {weight}; & \node[vartype] (zzz) {float}; & \\
    };
\node[structtype,above=0.5ex of attributes.north west,anchor=west]  {Attributes};
\end{tikzpicture}}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[struct] (person)
{
    \node[varname] {name};  & \node[vartype] {const char*}; \\
    \node[varname] {attrs}; & \node{\usebox{\tempbox}}; \\
    \node[varname] {xxx};   & \node (xxx) {TODO};  \\
};
\node[structtype,above=0.5ex of person.north west,anchor=west]  {Person};

\draw[->,very thick] (xxx.east) -- ++(2,0) |- (zzz.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document})
```

[image]

The problem is that the `(zzz)` node *can* be referenced but the outer image sees it in the wrong position. The problem can be highlighted by inserting extra stuff.

[image]

If the code worked at all, I would have expected something like this

[image]

I wasn't expecting the `(zzz)` node to even compile, but given that it does, **why does the arrow land where it does?**

(Note that adding X pixels of stuff above the inner picture does not move the arrow's endpoint down by X pixels: the endpoint doesn't seem to be a fixed distance from anything else in the drawing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the option `remember picture` to both `tikzpicture` environments.

```
\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(age.text),remember picture]
...
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
```

You have to run LaTeX twice to get the reference points right that are written to the `aux` file.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,intersections,shapes,backgrounds,scopes,positioning,fit,matrix}

%% Language and font encodings
\usepackage[english]{babel}% Really?

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{varname/.style={rectangle,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{vartype/.style={rectangle,text=red,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}
\tikzset{struct/.style={draw,matrix of nodes,column 1/.style={anchor=base west},column 2/.style={anchor=base west}}}
\tikzset{structtype/.style={rectangle,draw,fill=white,thin,inner sep=0.3ex,font=\ttfamily,text height=1.5ex,text depth=0.35ex}}

\setbox\tempbox=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(age.text),remember picture]
\matrix[struct] (attributes)
    {
        \node[varname] (age) {age};    & \node[vartype]       {int*}; & \\
        \node[varname]       {height}; & \node[vartype]       {float}; & \\
        \node[varname]       {weight}; & \node[vartype] (zzz) {float}; & \\
    };
\node[structtype,above=0.5ex of attributes.north west,anchor=west]  {Attributes};
\end{tikzpicture}}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\matrix[struct] (person)
{
    \node[varname] {name};  & \node[vartype] {const char*}; \\
    \node[varname] {name};  & \node[vartype] {const char*}; \\
    \node[varname] {name};  & \node[vartype] {const char*}; \\
    \node[varname] {attrs}; & \node{\usebox{\tempbox}}; \\
    \node[varname] {xxx};   & \node (xxx) {TODO};  \\
};
\node[structtype,above=0.5ex of person.north west,anchor=west]  {Person};

\draw[->,very thick] (xxx.east) -- ++(2,0) |- (zzz.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure that would work with a savebox. I should have realized that global definitions are saved imediately and the origin location will still be written to the aux file when the box is printed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I was also not sure until I had verified that it works. :-)